# inserir dado tipo date sqlite - java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Oi, estou tentando passar uma data definida pelo usuario para o banco de dados, mas sempre que clico em adicionar o aplicativo crasha e tenho o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date.

O código para adicionar os dados ao BD é:

```
 public void add(String date){
     
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, dateFormat.format(date));
```

E esse é o codigo que tenho na activity, para a chamar o datepickerdialog e passar os dados inseridos para o metodo que adiciona as informacões a db.

```
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar dataSelect = Calendar.getInstance();
                dataSelect.set(year,month,dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                adddate.setText(format.format(dataSelect.getTime()));
            }
        },calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        adddate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        btnsubtmit = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

        btnsubtmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DataBase myDB = new DataBase(AddTarefas.this);
                myDB.add(adddate.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// o correto para transformar uma string em um date é usar o parse
public void add(String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, dateFormat.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Como voce chama um DatePickerDialog, eu diria para voce mudar o campo
*adddate* para um *TextView*, e armazenar o resultado do *onDateSet()* em uma variavel *Date*, e passar para o db